# AWS policy for creating only the snapshots

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I have attached the following policy with an IAM user that should allow the user to create a snapshot of the EC2 instance (EBS backed).

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1473146965806",
        "Action": [
            "ec2:CreateSnapshot"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:*:MY_ACCOUNT_ID:*/*"
    }
]
}
```

But when the user tries to execute the command to create a snapshot, the following error occurs:

```
An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the CreateSnapshot 
operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.
```

What is incorrect in the policy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CreateSnapshot doesn't support resource-level permissions, you can use a wildcard for the **"Resource":"*"**:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1473146965806",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:CreateSnapshot"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html#ec2-api-unsupported-resource-permissions

Comment: aws role is prohibiting "Resource" word recently while creating role.